# Pointer field toUser needs a pointer value Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a Parse.com class called Messages, where I have 3 columns:

```
- fromUser - Pointer<_User>
- toUser - Pointer<_User>
- image - File
```

In my UITableView I'm trying to retrieve all objects in the Messages-class where toUser is equal to PFUser currentUser. I'm getting this error when I do the query:

```
UserInfo=0x1702e3580 {code=102, temporary=0, error=pointer field toUser needs a pointer value, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)"} {
    code = 102;
    error = "pointer field toUser needs a pointer value";
    originalError = "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)\"";
    temporary = 0;
}
```

Here's how I do the query:

```
- (void)retriveMessages {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit = 1000;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo);
        } else {
            // Found messages!
            self.messages = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common mistake to confuse objectIds with pointers.  Change the equalTo: test to:

```
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

**EDIT**
In JS/Cloud code, it works the same way:

```
var someParseObject = // probably from another query
query.equalTo("somePointerAttribute", someParseObject);

// in cloud functions with a request parameter, the requesting user is available
query.equalTo("pointerToAUserAttribute", request.user);
```

Comment: What about if we're not looking for a User?

Comment: The second argument to equalTo when comparing a pointer col is a PFObject. PFUser is a subclass.

Comment: can you please tell how to right this in cloud code?